# Cyclic Groups and prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The following example is given in my textbook:

Example: If $G$ is a group and $|G| = p^2$ then either $G$ is cyclic or $g^p = 1$ for every element $g \in G$

Solution: Assume that $G$ is not cyclic. Then $o(g) \mid p^2$ so $o(g) = 1$, $p$ or $p^2$. But $o(g)$ cannot be $p^2$ since $G$ is not cyclic, so $o(g)$ is $1$ or $p$. Either way $g^p = 1$.

What I do not understand is why the order of $g$ cannot be $p^2$ if $G$ is not cyclic. Thanks

Comment: you mean the order of $g$ here

Comment: If an element of a group has the same order as the order of the group itself, then that element is the generator of a cyclic group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of $g$ is $p^2$, then the elements $\{1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{p^2 - 1}\}$ are all distinct, hence $\left<g\right>$ has $p^2$ elements. Then $G = \left<g\right>$, so $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

If the finite group $G$ has an element $g$ of order $|G|$ then all elements of $G$ are powers of $g$, so $G$ is cyclic.